# Outputting the rows from an (ixj) array into individual (5xj/5) arrays in a text file

Tags: arrays, io, fortran

In a program I'm writing, I've created an allocated, final product array AFT(n,92). In my output I would like present each row as its own table, 5 columns wide.

So in this case, it would be n individual tables of 19 rows X 5 columns with only 2 values on the final row. I attempted doing this as a do loop as shown in the code snip below, but the output comes out as just one long column. I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
DO i=1,n
    WRITE(4,800) t(i), ' HHMM LDT'   !Writes the table header using an array which holds the corresponding time value
    800 FORMAT(14, A9)
    DO j=1,92
        WRITE(4,900) AFT(i,j)
        900 FORMAT(5ES23.14)
    END DO
END DO
```

I believe this is happening because the write command is performed for each j individually due to the use of a loop, but my inexperience with FORTRAN is leading me to a blank when I try to come up another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each write statement produces one line of text output.   If you want multiple items to be included in the same output record, you have to include them in the write statement.  If you want to include portions of an array, you can use techniques such as:

```
do i=1, N
   write (*, *) (array (i,j), j=1, 5)
end do
```

or

```
do i=1, N
   write (*, *) array (i, 1:5)
end do
```

The first is using implied do loops, the second array sections.

Comment: I amended my code utilizing the implied do option using j=1,92 and it worked. Thanks for the help!